# ag-grid Infinite scrolling Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript

anyone happens to have a setup for ag-grid in Angular 2 for infinite scrolling ?

I don't know how to set it up.
I have two models, for the request ( filters ) and for the response.
In the request model I have a parameter "PageNumber" who must be incremented each time ag-grid makes the request ( on scroll ).

On the response I have a parameter called "HasMoreRows" and if this is false. That means that I have no more data to request.

Request model:

```
export class PersonSearchModel {
    Resident: boolean;
    IdPerson: number;
    Country: string;
    IdentityDocumentTypeId: number;
    Type: number;
    Name: string;
    Cnp: string;
    Cui: string;
    IdentityDocumentType: string;
    SortName: string;
    SortOrder: string;
    PageNumber: number;
    PageSize: number; 
  }
```

Response model:

```
export interface PersonGridModel {
  HasMoreRows: boolean,
  Data: {
    IdPerson: number,
    Name: string,
    Type: string,
    CuiCnp: string,
    Resident: string,
    Country: string,
    IdentificationNumber: string,
    IdentityDocumentType: string,
    CreatedOn: string,
    CreatedBy: string,
    ModifiedBy: string,
    ModifiedOn: string
  }
}
```